# How do I store data that is shared between databases?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, schema, foreign-keys

How do I store data that is shared between databases?

Suppose a database for a contact management system. Each user is given a separate database. User can store his/her contacts' education information.

Currently there's a table called `School` in every database where the name of every school in the country is stored. School table is referenced as a FK by Contact table.

School table gets updated every year or so, as new schools get added or existing schools change names.

As the school information is common across all user databases, moving it into a separate common database seems to be a better idea. but when it's moved to a separate database, you can not create a FK constraint between `School` and `Contact`.

What is the best practice for this kind of situation?

(p.s. I'm using SQL Server if that is relevant)

Comment: Why are you giving each user a separate database?

Comment: I'm giving each user a separate database because each user is an entire organization that would be using the software, with lots of data.

Comment: How common will queries against tables that should be FKed to the `Schools` table be?

Comment: when user looks up that contact's education information, which is not that often. or there are situations where user searches for all contacts that graduated from certain school.

Comment: as a sidenote, I found this answer for using separate DB for each user. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-a-single-database-for-each-client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to consider

- Database is a unit of backup/restore.
- It may not be possible to restore two databases to the same point in time.
- Foreign keys are not supported across databases.

Hence, I would suggest managing the `School` -- and any other common table -- in one reference DB and then replicating those tables to other DBs.

Answer (score 1):

Just straight out of the box, foreign key constraints aren't going to help you. You could look into replicating the individual schools table.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that you won't query tables with the `SchoolID` column very often I'll asume that inserts/updates to these tables will be really rare... In this case you could create a constraint on the table in which you need the FKs that checks for the existence of such `SchoolID` in the `Schools` table.

Note that every insert/update to the table with the `SchoolID` column will literally perform a query to another DB so, distance between databases, the way they connect to each other and many other factors may impact the performance of the insert/update statements.

Still, if they're on the same server and you have your indexes and primary keys all set up, the query should be fairly fast.