# One database vs many databases

Tags: mysql, database, multi-tenant

I know the question has been asked many times but I'd like an answer for my case.

I'm working on a web application which will allow my clients to manage their clients, encashments, invoices, reservations, a website, and many other things. I'm using MySQL and one database with about 30 tables.

I'd like my solution to be able to handle around 100,000 clients or more. The needs of my clients will be very different. From 100 inserts per year for one, to 1000 inserts per day for another.

For now I'm using one database (but I'm still in development) where each table has an account field. I've created a model layer to access the data which automatically append the account to each query (*WHERE guid = 1* become *WHERE account = X AND guid = 1*). This work very well and is really easy to maintain, but I'm worried about the fact of mixing the data of my clients. Note that I'm using an incremental id instead of a GUID.

My question is, should I continue to do things like this or should I create one database per client?

Comment: Do you *have* 100,000 clients right now? If not, you are way pre-optimizing by trying to have that as a requirement.

Comment: And the answer to you question is a huge "it depends". Without more details about the specifics, there is nothing that can be said.

Comment: What more details do you want ? As I say, I'm still in dev so I just have few testers. But I was thinking that this kind of thing should be think before opening my application to the public. Am I wrong ?

Comment: the best solution will be, to have a schema having all the metadata like ur clientid and to that their schema(database) will be mapped.
Is it possible to have a schema for every client???

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the advantages of using a single database for EACH client?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-a-single-database-for-each-client)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking at a multi-tenant database.  Multi-tenant solutions range from one database per client (shared nothing) to one row per client (shared everything).

"Shared nothing" is the most expensive per client. Large numbers of clients imply large numbers of servers. Client disaster recovery is simple and straightforward. "Shared nothing" reduces the possibility of accidentally exposing client data to almost zero.

"Shared everything" is the least expensive per client. Every table has a column that identifies which client a row belongs to. Client disaster recovery is very complicated; you have to restore individual rows in every table. "Shared everything" is the architecture most likely to accidentally expose client data.

Microsoft has a good article on [multi-tenant architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx).  Their terminology is

- separate database (shared nothing)
- separate schema
- shared schema (shared everything)

Comment: well written, I also tried to brief this, but ur answer is superb.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the article. It seems to me that a separate schema is the best option for me, but, from what I know, mysql doesn't allow it. So now, I have 3 options, stay like this, move to PostgreSQL (which seem to me a good option), or use a separate database (looks like a bad option since I don't expect to do specific dev for a client). Any advice ?

Comment: Personally, I'd rather work with PostgreSQL than MySQL. But more web hosts offer MySQL than PostgreSQL. A MySQL database isn't that much different from a PostgreSQL schema. Both provide a namespace, and MySQL can query across databases like PostgreSQL queries across schemas. PostgreSQL doesn't support direct querying across two databases.

Comment: Well I'm using a dedicated server so I can use what I want. My main concern is about maintenance. I'd love to separate my user data, but I'd like to be able to easily add a column in a table for all my user (and so all the databases or schemas). Now that I understand better the schema concept, it seems that it will not change anything if I use 1 schema per user or 1 database per user. So, as you said, using a MySQL database per user or a PostgreSQL schema per user will be almost the same (and really the same from a maintenance perspective).